# Sub Queries and fetching data from two tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to list the `horse_id`, `horse_name` for each `horse` that has **placed in the top 3** (e.g was place 1,2 or 3) **two or more** times. HINT: Try using `WHERE...IN...`

I'm pretty sure I'll have to get data from the `HORSE` table, which includes the `horse_id` and `horse_name`, and data from the `PRIZE` table, which includes the column `PLACE` (place the horse was). But the `PLACE` table only has the columns `EVENT_id`, `Place` and `Money`, so I'm not sure how to join it with the horse table.

Comment: Can you give more details on your three tables please; like field names/types.

Comment: There should be more tables / columns you are not telling us about.

Comment: There is an entry table I can link it to. ENTRY table columns are Event_id, Horse_id, Place. May work that way better as there is a horse_id in that table as well ?

Comment: My main question I guess is really figuring out how to select the horses that have come place 1,2,3 more than two times

Comment: You need to post your table schema, as well as sample data, as well as expected output from that data

Comment: Sample data:
FROM HORSE TABLE:
HORSE_ID = 101, 102,201, 301
Horse_Name = Flash, Star, Boxer, Daisy

FROM ENTRY TABLE:
Event_id = 101, 101, 101, 101
Horse_id = 101, 102, 201, 301
Place = 1, 2, 3, 4

Expected output:
+ ------------- + --------- + | horse_id | name | + ------------- + --------- + | 101 | Flash | | 201 | Boxer | | NULL | NULL | + ------------- + --------- +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to make out your tables and data since you posted it in the comments instead of the question, but try this.

```
select horse.* 
  from horse
    inner join entry
      on horse.horse_id = entry.horse_id
  where entry.place <= 3
  group by horse.horse_id
  having count(horse.horse_id) >= 2
```

Comment: Hi.

Am getting ERROR CODE 1054. UNKNOWN COLUMN ENTRY.PLACE IN WHERE CLAUSE. Hmm

Comment: according to what you posted in the comments, entry has a place column.  can you please post the output of `show create table` for all your tables, in the question?

Comment: Will do that in two seconds. Just quickly though, with what you posted, where and how can I implement the 'two or more times' part ? Thanks.

Comment: @JerryMegur have you had an opportunity to test this one out now?

Comment: Yes I have, worked beautifully. Thought i marked it as answered, musn't of

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT horse_id,name
FROM HORSE
WHERE horse_id IN
(SELECT horse_id
FROM ENTRY
WHERE place <= 3
GROUP BY horse_id
HAVING count(horse_id) > 1);
```